Issue with css margin property margin: 0px auto;
I'm trying to build responsive navbar in reactjs
navbar.jsx
const CustomNavbar = () => {
    return (
        <header className="main row">
            <nav className="xs-col-11 col-10">
                <div className="menu xs-col-12 col-12">
                    <div className="left-menu">
                        <div className="brand-image">
                            Blog App 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </header>
    );
}

my css file is:-
navbar-design.css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
}

.main {
    background-color: #0080ff;
    height: 3.7em;
}

nav {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.menu {
    height: 3.7em;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

and this is my custom grid layout css file
rwd-layout.css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    /* padding: 15px; */
}

html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans",
        sans-serif;
}

/* for mobiles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* for mobile  */
    [class*="xs-col-1"] { width: 8.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-2"] { width: 16.66% }

    [class*="xs-col-3"] { width: 25%; }
    
    [class*="xs-col-4"] { width: 33.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-5"] { width: 41.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-6"] { width: 50%; }

    [class*="xs-col-7"] { width: 58.33% ;}

    [class*="xs-col-8"] { width: 66.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-9"] { width: 75%; }

    [class*="xs-col-10"] { width: 83.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-11"] { width: 91.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-12"] { width: 100%; }
}

.center {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

/* for tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* for tablet layout */
    .col-s-1 { width: 8.33%; }
    .col-s-2 { width: 16.66%; }
    .col-s-3 { width: 25%; }
    .col-s-4 { width: 33.33%; }
    .col-s-5 { width: 41.66%; }
    .col-s-6 { width: 50%; }
    .col-s-7 { width: 58.33%; }
    .col-s-8 { width: 66.66%; }
    .col-s-9 { width: 75%; }
    .col-s-10 { width: 83.33%; }
    .col-s-11 { width: 91.66%; }
    .col-s-12 { width: 100%; }
}

/* for desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* for desktop */
    .col-1 { width: 8.33%; }
    .col-2 { width: 16.66%; }
    .col-3 { width: 25%; }
    .col-4 { width: 33.33%; }
    .col-5 { width: 41.66%; }
    .col-6 { width: 50%; }
    .col-7 { width: 58.33%; }
    .col-8 { width: 66.66%; }
    .col-9 { width: 75%; }
    .col-10 { width: 83.33%; }
    .col-11 { width: 91.66%; }
    .col-12 { width: 100%; }
}

the problem is when apply margin:0px auto; to nav element not take center position why? I don't know what is wrong here please tell me what I'm doing wrong here that preventing margin:0px auto;
I also try various solution but none of work try to troubleshoot the problem in various ways like:
1)
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav.xs-col-11.col-12 {
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        margin: 0px auto !important;
    }
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* for mobile  */
    [class*="xs-col-1"] { width: 8.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-2"] { width: 16.66% }

    [class*="xs-col-3"] { width: 25%; }
    
    [class*="xs-col-4"] { width: 33.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-5"] { width: 41.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-6"] { width: 50%; }

    [class*="xs-col-7"] { width: 58.33% ;}

    [class*="xs-col-8"] { width: 66.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-9"] { width: 75%; }

    [class*="xs-col-10"] { width: 83.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-11"] { width: 91.66%; margin: 0px auto; }

    [class*="xs-col-12"] { width: 100%; margin: 0px auto; }
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* for mobile  */
    [class*="xs-col-1"] { width: 8.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-2"] { width: 16.66% }

    [class*="xs-col-3"] { width: 25%; }
    
    [class*="xs-col-4"] { width: 33.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-5"] { width: 41.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-6"] { width: 50%; }

    [class*="xs-col-7"] { width: 58.33% ;}

    [class*="xs-col-8"] { width: 66.66%; }

    [class*="xs-col-9"] { width: 75%; }

    [class*="xs-col-10"] { width: 83.33%; }

    [class*="xs-col-11"] { width: 91.66%; margin: 0px auto !important; }

    [class*="xs-col-12"] { width: 100%; margin: 0px auto !important; }
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav.xs-col-11.col-12 {
        margin: 0px auto !important;
    }
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav.xs-col-11.col-12 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}


What's in your .row styles? Try and make a runnable snippet with the issue you're having

@Zach Jensz code of my row is: .row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
} please help me why margin: 0px auto; prevent? I edit my question you can check now.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The issue you're facing with centering the nav is likely due to the fact that it has a width set to 100% by default so setting margin: 0 auto; does not have any effect because there is no room for it to be centered.
quick fix:
nav {
    max-width: 90%; /* Set a maximum width less than 100% */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the nav */
}

If you are using custom grid classes (xs-col-11 col-10), make sure these classes are not conflicting or overriding the widths.
